# CORS configured server giving inconsistent responses on axios get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors, axios

I'm making get requests to an express route using cors middleware. I'm trying to receive a json object. However the results from this are inconsistent. If I disable cross origin restrictions in chrome or safari and make a request it works fine. However if I try to make use of the cors middleware and enable the standard cross origin restrictions, my get requests only receive the json object about half the time. Sometimes I get the object, most times I receive nothing and my props get set to null from the redux store.

Here's the relevant server code

```
var app = express()
var corsOptions = {
  'origin': true,
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  'preflightContinue': true,
  'optionsSuccessStatus': 204}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(require('morgan')('combined'))
app.use(require('cookie-parser')())
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.get('/',
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.json(req.user)
  }
)
```

And here is the relevant axios request in my component through a redux store

```
export function loginWithTwitter () {
  return function thunk (dispatch) {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      responseType: 'json',
      headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
    })
      .then(res =>
        res.data
      )
      .then(user => {
        const action = twitterLogin(user)
        dispatch(action)
      })
      .catch(console.error())
  }
}
```

If extract the axios request and make the request within the component and try to set state locally, I get the same issue. Is it a race condition? What could be causing inconsistent issues? I should note that I never receive an error and the server status always comes back successful. Also hitting the route in a separate browser window ALWAYS returns the correct json.

Comment: "I get the same error" --- what error?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I never receive an error, it just gets set to a null value.

Comment: did u try with `preflightContinue` to false  ?

Comment: @Panther Just tried, still only receive the correct response about half the time.

Comment: i think the error is from the function `twitterlogin`. try to console log use just before calling Twitterlogin and see if twitter login is causing the issue. i think ur API is fine and twitter login is the culprit.

Comment: @Panther Ok so I just console logged user before calling twitter login and it gives me a null value. So then I tried to log the res from the axios request and the data on my response is empty as well. So I feel like the issue might be due to how I'm making the axios request but I'm unsure. Why would it be giving me the proper response about half the time though? Its so strange.